# Projections of the twisted cubic curve from points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

**I.** Consider the twisted cubic curve $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$, given as the image of the veronese map $v_3: \mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^3$. Let $p \in \mathbb{P}^3 $ and consider the projection $\pi: C \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ of $C$ from $p$. In particular, consider the two choices of points: $ p_1=[1:0:0:1]$ and $p_2=[0:1:0:0]$.

**II.** Next, consider the action of the projective general linear group $PGL(2,k)$ on $\mathbb{P}^3$, where $k$ is the underlying algebraically closed field. If we view $\mathbb{P}^3$ as the space of polynomials (modulo scalar multiplication) of degree $3$ in $2$ variables, then the orbits under the above action are three: the first consists of elements of the form $(a_1 x_1+a_2 x_2)^3$, which are precisely the elements of $C$, the second has elements $(a_1 x_1+a_2 x_2)^2(b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2)$, with the linear forms $a_1 x_1+a_2 x_2, b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2$ independent, and the third one consists of elements of the form $(a_1 x_1+a_2 x_2)(b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2)(c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2)$, with the appearing linear forms being pairwise independent.

**Question:** Why does **II** imply that the image of $C$ projected from any point $p$ is projectively equivalent to either its image projected from $p_1$ or to its image projected from $p_2$?

**Reference:** Harris, Algebraic Geometry: A First Course, Example 10.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the projection of $C$ from a point $p$ that is not on the curve. 
Then for any automorphism $g\colon \mathbb{P}^3 \to \mathbb{P}^3$ you get an equivalence with the projection of $g(C)$ from the point $g(p)$.

In particular, you just need to find an automorphism $g\colon \mathbb{P}^3 \to \mathbb{P}^3$ such that $g(C)=C$ and $g(p)=p_1$ or $g(p)=p_2$. I think that looking at $\mathbb{P}^3$ as the space of polynomials modulo scalar multiplication, you should have that $p_1=[1,0,0,1]$ corresponds to $x_1^3+x_2^3$ and $p_2=[0,1,0,0]$ corresponds to $x_1^2x_2$. You can see that $x_1^3+x_2^3$ is the product of three linearly independent linear forms, so that  II tells you that you can always find such a $g$ by considering the action of $PGL(2,k)$.